# Removing a many-to-many relationship (when you have only the entity ids)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to remove an user from a topic (many-to-many relationship), but it says, that `topic.Users` is null. What am i doing wrong?

```
var user = new User { Id = userId };
var topic = new Topic { Id = topicId };
context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Topics.Attach(topic);
topic.Users.Remove(user);
```

**Entity classes**

Topic:

```
[InverseProperty("TopicsSubscribed")]
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

User:

```
public virtual ICollection<Topic> TopicsSubscribed { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show the entity classes?

Comment: Added to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation properties (`Users` in this case) are not loaded, because your `topic` entity is not wrapped by a dynamic proxy and therefore the navigation properties do not get lazy loaded.

You can explicitly load the `Users` property like this:

```
var user = new User { Id = userId };
var topic = new Topic { Id = topicId };
context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Topics.Attach(topic);
context.Entry(topic).Collection(t => t.Users).Load();  // explicitly load Users ...
topic.Users.Remove(user);
```

Comment: Tried that, i got this: "The property 'Users' on type 'Topic' is a collection navigation property. The Collection method should be used instead of the Reference method.".

Comment: Oh, sorry my fault. Updated my answer. You have to call `.Collection` instead of `.Reference` of course.

Comment: Thank you. Works like it's supposed to. :)